# Facelets ui:repeat tag breaks JSF form validation

Tags: java, validation, jsf, facelets

I have the following JSF page (it's kind of typed in pseudocode, to make it visible):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><h:inputText id="field1" value="#{Bean.singleField.value}" required="true"/></td>
        <td>
            <ui:repeat value="#{Bean.listOfFields} var="field">
                <h:inputText value="#{field.value}/>
            </ui:repeat>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If field1 is not filled in (so empty) and  I submit the form, the form validates to false. That's perfect.
But all values I've entered in the input boxes inside the ui:repeat tag will not be restored after a negative validation. All fields are empty again!
The values do get restored, if I use "a4j:repeat". Is there something wrong with the ui:repeat tag?

Kind regards,

Jochen

Comment: Is `ui:repeat` nested in another `ui:repeat`?

Comment: I see, there is a bug with nested iterative components like `ui:repeat` and `h:dataTable` but if there is no nesting I'd expect it to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Mojarra version 2.0.3 and I just found this bug in JSF Facelets ... 
It's a bug, which is solved in a later version: http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1807

Comment: Lesson learned: Keep yourself up to date. 2.0.3 is over 2 years old already.